# Adding content in MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm new to [Monogame](http://www.monogame.net/). I'm trying to add content (An image), but I can't do this. In each tutorial that I have seen, the solution explorer has a folder where I can put assets, but not mine.

I tried to add an image to the root folder, but it doesn't work.

```
hero = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Image1.png");
```

Comment: "_it doesn't work._" How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your solution and click **Add**, then **New Project**.

From there, select **Installed > Visual C# > Monogame**, and click on the **MonoGame Content Project**

After you do this, you will see your content project in your solution. In order to allow your game to use it, look under your *Game* project, and right click **References**. Navigate to **Solution > Projects** and tick the checkbox next to your *Content* project.

You can now add your images to your *Content* project, and use them like a regular XNA game.

Check out these links:

- [Managing Content |
  Monogame](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/monogame-managing-content)
- [Loading Content in XNA
  (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203875.aspx)

Comment: This is now done through the [http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=Using_The_Pipeline_Tool](MonoGame Pipeline Tool).  There is no longer a MonoGame Content project.